# How do I execute a remote command in Powershell interactively?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'd like to run a command on a remote machine interactively using PowerShell, similar to how when passing an argument to `ssh` it runs just that program. For instance, this would open a connection, execute `program` and then return back to your normal shell.

```sh
$ ssh username@somehost program
```

I know I can use `Enter-PSSession` to get into the session, but I'd have to manually enter the program name. If I use `Invoke-Command` with `-Session`, I can get it to execute the program I want, but then that program crashes if it's expecting user input.

Comment: from what i can tell the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet is NOT for interactive use. the `-Session` is NOT for _entering_ a PSSession, it is for _using one non-interactively_. i suggest you read up on the way the `Enter-PSSession` can be used. i think it simply runs the next lines of the script on the remote system.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey You can do `$s = New-PSSession computer1; Enter-PSSession -Session $s`

Comment: What is the actual command you're trying to run?  I can do `read-host` over invoke-command, but not `cmd /c copy con`.

Comment: @js2010 I'm trying to invoke a python script that's located on the server. It should be transparent to the user that it's executing there and not on the local machine, but the script may (and will) require some input. This is being launched in a .NET application.

Comment: Why don't you run it off a fileshare?

Comment: @js2010 The idea is to avoid having to make the users have a copy of Python installed. The script also requires packages which are sensitive to versioning and we don't want users to have to set that up or spend time activating an environment. The idea is a server could execute it in a controlled environment.

Comment: @js2010 - yes, that is what the `Enter-PSSession` stuff is for. my point is that the `Invoke-Command` parameter does not _enter_ a session ... it uses a session to connect in a non-interactive way. that is what it seems to do from what i understand.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look good.  Looking for a way to run it off a fileshare might be easier.

```
invoke-command comp001 { python -c "raw_input('type something')" }

Traceback (most recent call last):
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : arc001

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
type something
```